# Summing values in two columns based on a single userId

Tags: excel

How can I combine data if userIdA and userIdB are the same. The result would be the data stored in userId, ValA, and    ValB

```
ValA        userIdA   ValB  userIdB     userId  ValA    ValB
2           1227      16    1025        1227    2       17
12          1251      40    1213        1251    12      44
1           1279      17    1227                
7           1452      44    1251                
2           1466      16    1261
```

Answer (score 0):

One formula you're looking for `SUMIF`. See below.

[image]

[image]

```
G2: =SUMIF($B:$B,$F2,$A:$A)
H2: =SUMIF($D:$D,$F2,$C:$C)
```

Both dragged down.